# Extending the universal property of tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, universal-property

Suppose that we defined a tensor product of vector spaces $U$ and $V$ as a quotient of a vector space with basis $V \times W$ by the vector space spanned by
$-(u_1+u_2,v)+(u_1,v)+(u_2,v), -(u,v_1+v_2)+(u,v_1)+(u,v_2),-(au,v)+(u,av)$.

I have proved the universal property for two vector spaces. But how then extend it to a tensor product of $n$ vector spaces?

Comment: What goes wrong with trying to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define it recursively by $V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_n = \left( V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_{n-1} \right) \otimes V_n$, but you want to check associativity.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/348192/6509).

Comment: Well, I proved that for vector spaces $U,V,W$, $U \otimes (V \otimes W) \cong (U \otimes V) \otimes W$. But how can we now "recursively" say that for any multilinear map $V_1 \times ... \times V_n \rightarrow U$ we have a unique linear transformation $V_1 \otimes ... \otimes V_n \rightarrow U$?